# Lambda Won't Detect The Layer

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have a python3.8, and I created a new folder and installed pandas in it using

```
pip3 install pandas -t .
```

Next thing - zipped the folder (the zipped folder is 38Mb), and uploaded to s3.

Created a Layer and added the s3 path of zip file in it (also set the runtime env to python3.8 here)

Next I created a lambda function with python3.8 and test its skeleton first and it worked.

Added the layer to the lambda function and imported pandas. And now when I run the test, it does not detect pandas and gives me Module Not Found error.

What can I be doing wrong here?

Comment: Could be many reasons. What exactly is your OS? Did you use exactly same OS as lambda is using?

Comment: @Marcin, I created zip on my local machines. Tried both windows and OSX.

Comment: There are public pandas layers. So if you need only panda, you could look at them. Have you considered that?

Comment: My pandas issues has been solved, but I am still interested in making use of public layers. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you created a folder named python and put all the package files inside it? Also another supporting package Pytz is required to run panda in lambda. I use MAC OSX to create the zip file but the root folder needs to be named as "python".

The creation of the zip file is little bit lengthy to describe here, I suggest you to go through [this document](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-add-python-pandas-layer-to-aws-lambda-bab5ea7ced4f). Also naming convention is equally important. I think if you follow the document and create the zip file and upload it directly (or via S3) to create lambda layer then it will definitely work.

Comment: I did not fully understand the logic behind how this process worked. However, this medium article you shared is a life saver. It helped solve my issue.

Comment: I don't know how many times I've tried this but I can't get it to work despite following that medium article.

Comment: It was this YouTube video which actually tells you how to unpack the *correct* Wheel file version no matter your OS!! : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1UDEp90S9h8

Answer (score 1):

There's now a managed layer that includes Pandas, so you don't need to create your own. It's called "[AWS SDK for pandas](https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)" (aka `awswrangler`, formerly "AWS data wrangler"). You can add it to your AWS Lambda function by going Lambda > Layers > Add layer > AWS layers, then selecting AWSSDKPandas-Python311 (or similar) from the drop-down list.